# Google sheets error: Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My IMPORTXML functions sometimes work, but sometimes don't. When they don't, I get the following error:

Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.

I tried downloading the website, and then hosting only the HTML at a domain that I own. When I do this, I am able to import using IMPORTXML, but my data obviously won't update automatically.

Is there a way to overcome this by somehow forcing the IMPORTXML function to only look at the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a custom function that technically grabs all of it. If it is really a ton of content then wrap the `(.*)` with the content that surrounds the real content you want... such as `<head>(.*)<\/head>` (just for example sake)

```
function importWebsite(url) {
  var found, html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    if (html) content = html.match(/^(.*)/gi)[0];
  }
  return content;
}
```

Comment: When I use this code it only imports the <!DOCTYPE html>. I tried playing with the `if (html) content = html.match(/^(.*)/gi)[0];` portion, but can't seem to get it to work. When I get rid of the .match part entirely, I get an error saying that it can't exceed 50000 characters. When I change the regex like this 'if (html) content = html.match(/^<section>(.*)</section>/gi)[0];', the cell is blank and it doesn't pull in any data. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll test in a sec when I get back but just to note you need to escape the backslash in the `</section>` part, should look like `<\/section>`

Comment: Just tried `content = html.match(/^<section>(.*)<\/section>/gi);` but it's still just pulling a blank cell.

Comment: For reference, here is the URL I'm trying to pull data from: https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/mlb?date=2017-07-09&site=draftkings

Comment: Leave off the `^`

Comment: Oh ok perfect let me check

Comment: which part of the data are you actually wanting to get? which portions are the most important?

Comment: each of the lineups. I'm sometimes able to pull it using the importxml function, but sometimes I can't (like in this case for the July 9th lineups).

Comment: I have a few options but i gotta leave for work right now - can you share a doc with me that shows the xpaths your also trying - because xpaths worked for me perfectly fine - it might be that your being too specific or not specific enough with the tags

Comment: Below is a link to a test sheet. Notice that IMPORTXML works fine for FanDuel, but not for DraftKings. This is usually the case, but sometimes it works for both (typically on Mondays and Thursdays when there are fewer lineups), and sometimes it doesn't work for either. The error is always "Resource at URL contents exceeded maximum size."

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1555J9Yg2XSpkhTMeGNeulRmRsOWoosG88WqptjlJ4P0/edit?usp=sharing